# Adding the "Clear" Button to an iPhone UITextField

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uikit

How do you add that little "X" button on the right side of a UITextField that clears the text?  I can't find an attribute for adding this sub-control in Interface Builder in the iPhone OS 2.2 SDK.

**Note:** In Xcode 4.x and later (iPhone 3.0 SDK and later), you can do this in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 376, accepted):

This button is a built-in overlay that is provided by the `UITextField` class, but as of the iOS 2.2 SDK, there isn't any way to set it via Interface Builder.  You have to enable it programmatically.

Add this line of code somewhere (`viewDidLoad`, for example):

**Objective-C**

```
myUITextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
```

**Swift 5.0**

```
myUITextField.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
```

Answer (score 66):

You can also set this directly from Interface Builder under the Attributes Inspector.

[image]

Taken from XCode 5.1

Comment: Note that the question specifically asks about the 2.2 SDK, and notes that this option is available in Interface Builder in later versions.

Answer (score 51):

Swift 4+:

```
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextField.ViewMode.whileEditing
```

or even shorter:

```
textField.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
```

Comment: Fix enum type. Must not start from capital letter.

Answer (score 35):

you can add custom clear button and control the size and every thing using this:

```
UIButton *clearButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[clearButton setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[clearButton setFrame:frame];
[clearButton addTarget:self action:@selector(clearTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

textField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways; //can be changed to UITextFieldViewModeNever,    UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing,   UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing
[textField setRightView:clearButton];
```

Answer (score 8):

Objective C :

```
self.txtUserNameTextfield.myUITextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
```

Swift :

```
txtUserNameTextfield.clearButtonMode = UITextField.ViewMode.WhileEditing;
```

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 4** (adapted from Kristopher Johnson's answer)

```
textfield.clearButtonMode = .always

textfield.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing

textfield.clearButtonMode = .unlessEditing

textfield.clearButtonMode = .never
```

Answer (score 7):

this don't work, do like me:

> swift:

```
customTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextField.ViewMode.Always

customTextField.clearsOnBeginEditing = true;

func textFieldShouldClear(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 7):

On Xcode 8 (8A218a):

Swift:

```
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextField.ViewMode.whileEditing;
```

The "W" went from capital to non-cap "w".

Answer (score 1):

```
  func clear_btn(box_is : UITextField){
    box_is.clearButtonMode = .always
    if let clearButton = box_is.value(forKey: "_clearButton") as? UIButton {
        let templateImage =  clearButton.imageView?.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)

        clearButton.setImage(templateImage, for: .normal)
        clearButton.setImage(templateImage, for: .highlighted)

        clearButton.tintColor = .white

     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below lines of code. If rightView is there clear button is not showing.

```
self.txtField.rightView = nil
self.txtField.rightViewMode = .never
self.txtField.clearButtonMode = UITextField.ViewMode.always
```

Answer (score -4):

On Xcode Version 8.1 (8B62) it can be done directly in Attributes Inspector. Select the textField and then choose the appropriate option from Clear Button drop down box, which is located in Attributes Inspector.