# UITextField - clearButtonMode only in code, not in IB?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

Is there anyway possible to set the clearButtonMode for a UITextField in Interface Builder? Is this only possible to do code? I do not see it as an option in the UITextField attributes panel.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do it in Interface Builder (as of the 2.2 SDK)

See [Adding the "Clear" Button to an iPhone UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320078/adding-the-clear-button-to-an-iphone-uitextfield)

**UPDATE:** As of the latest version of XCode/SDK this property is now supported in IB.