# In the iOS SDK, how can I include a button in a UITextField like Mobile Safari does?

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

How can I display a button and/or activity indicator inside of a UITextField on the iPhone? I'm trying to reproduce Mobile Safari's location text field which contains either a reload button or a cancel (stop loading) button which is right-justified inside of the text field.

Similarly, when you click inside of the text field (not on the cancel/reload buttons) to edit the URL, a clear icon (x inside of a circle) is shown inside of the text field which will erase the contents of the text field.

How can I create this in my own apps? I cannot seem to do it via Interface Builder so I suspect it's being done in code.

Comment: Are you certain this is not just a clever layering of views and limited text field delegate resignation?

Answer (score 1):

There is a built in option that worked for me...check here:

[Adding the "Clear" Button to an iPhone UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320078/adding-the-clear-button-to-an-iphone-uitextfield)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [TTMessageController](http://three20.info/overview).