# iphone Development - UITextField - Display (X) on the right

Tags: iphone, button, uitextfield

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Adding the “Clear” Button to an iPhone UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320078/adding-the-clear-button-to-an-iphone-uitextfield)

hey there,
i created a UITextField and i want to add an (X) -CLEAR- button to the right of it.
The regular button that clears what is already written in the textfield.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

set the [clearButtonMode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006888-CH3-SW24)

```
field.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
field.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
field.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing;
field.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
```

or use Interface Builder, it has a setting for the clear button as well.

Answer (score 0):

Set the text field's `clearButtonMode`. See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/clearButtonMode).