# Clear button on UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, textfield

I have a UITextField with date picker, and I want to use the default built in button to clear the text field, it doesn't seems to work.

I tried overriding

```
func textFieldShouldClear(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        searchBar.text = "" //my textfield is called searchBar and I tried to clear the text like that
        return true
    }
```

It seems that the method is called and printing the textfield says its empty but its not and in the view shows the last date I entered. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide more code?

Comment: check this. https://stackoverflow.com/q/320078/6783598 .     searchBar.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing

Comment: I tried that, I am using the textfield either like a normal textfield or with date picker, when its not a date picker its all good and clear button is working, I guess it is something to do with the date picker, but I can't figure it out yet.

Comment: Have you set  delegate on the textfield ?

Comment: Yep, absolutely..

Answer (score 0):

You are searching this:
 `textfield.clearButtonMode`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to replace searchBar with textField (local variable) in the function like this?

```
func textFieldShouldClear(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.text = "" // use local variable textfield here
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that clear button is updating the text field and still takes the date from the date picker... Now I am trying to clear the value of the date picker maybe this will work.