# Is there a way to reset the value of textfield by clicking the button? [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, button, reset

I want to know how to reset the value entered in the textfield by pressing the button.

When I was doing java, I remembered that it was possible with just one command line, but I was wondering if there was such a way for Swift, so I ask a question.

ex) If you click the reset button after entering the value hi in the text field, the value hi is cleared.

Comment: possible duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/q/320078/2303865

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could simply do this inside your IBAction func

```
yourTextFieldOutlet.text = ""
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a built-in clear button that you can enable like this:

```
textField.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
```

[image]

This adds a clear button while the user is editing your text field.

Alternatively, you can just set the text to "" as @Arya Surya said.